# Unable to Play Sound correctly Using Android AudioTrack

Tags: android, audiotrack

I am running this program which uses AudioTrack to play a sound file from the resource folder. There' output but the sound is incorrect.

The Project file is uploaded.

http://www.mediafire.com/?995mxc87hf28fxk

```
   package com.self.AudioTrack;

  import java.io.IOException;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Context;
 import android.os.Bundle;

public class AudioTrack2Activity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Context ctx;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ctx=getApplicationContext();
    new Thread( new Runnable( ) 
    {
      // private Object context;

    public void run( )
       {                

          AudioDevice device = new AudioDevice(ctx);
         // String filepath="R.raw.cheerapp.mp3";
         // InputStream cheerSound = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cheerapp);
          //InputStream cheerSound = this.getContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cheerapp);
          try {
            device.PlayShortAudioFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       }

    } ).start();


}
```

}

```
  package com.self.AudioTrack;

  import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
  import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
  import java.io.DataInputStream;
  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.FileInputStream;
  import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStream;

  import android.content.Context;
  import android.media.AudioFormat;
  import android.media.AudioManager;
  import android.media.AudioTrack;

  public class AudioDevice
```

{

```
  AudioTrack track;
   short[] buffer = new short[1024];
   Context context;

   public AudioDevice(Context context_)
   {
      int minSize =AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize( 44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT );        
      track = new AudioTrack( AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100, 
                                        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 
                                        minSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
      context=context_;
      track.play();        
   }



   public void PlayShortAudioFile() throws IOException
   {
     InputStream in=context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cheerapp);   


    byte[] music = null;
     music = new byte[in.available()];

     music=convertStreamToByteArray(in);
     in.close();

      track.play();
      track.write(music, 0, music.length); 
     track.stop();
     track.release();
   } //Play



   public static byte[] convertStreamToByteArray(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buff = new byte[10240];
        int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        while ((i = is.read(buff, 0, buff.length)) > 0) {
            baos.write(buff, 0, i);
        }

        return baos.toByteArray(); // be sure to close InputStream in calling function
    }
```

}

Comment: First things first, have you double-checked your sample rate, stereo/mono, and encoding configuration to make sure they match the actual audio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry but these audio files are mpeg file which contain headers in it.The method you r using will work only for raw audio file with no header.If u want to play mp3 file use Mediaplayer (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

Comment: Ok, I converted then into wave.